# Strange Descriptor Behavior

Tags: python, descriptor

When the `__get__`, `__set__`, or `__delete__` attribute of a descriptor is not a method, and is instead a generic callable, the first argument of that callable is inconsistent:

---

```
class Callable(object):

    def __call__(self, first, *args, **kwargs):
        print(first)


class Descriptor(object):

    __set__ = Callable()
    __delete__ = Callable()
    __get__ = Callable()


class MyClass(object):

    d = Descriptor()


mc = MyClass()
mc.d = 1
del mc.d
mc.d
```

---

```
<__main__.MyClass object at 0x10854cda0>
<__main__.MyClass object at 0x10854cda0>
<__main__.Descriptor object at 0x10855f240>
```

---

Why is the owner descriptor passed to the first argument of `__get__` callable when this attribute is not technically a "method"? And perhaps more importantly, why is this behavior not consistent across all the descriptor attributes?

What's going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The relevant parts of the CPython internals just weren't implemented consistently. This may be considered a bug, although I don't know what promises Python makes about proper descriptor handling for this case.

I can explain exactly what happens internally, but since there are multiple layers of descriptor handling here, things are going to get confusing.

---

For a `__set__` or `__delete__` implemented in Python, the CPython internals use [`slot_tp_descr_set`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Objects/typeobject.c#L6381) to wrap it at the C level. (Yes, one C function for both of those methods.)

```
static int
slot_tp_descr_set(PyObject *self, PyObject *target, PyObject *value)
{
    PyObject *res;
    _Py_IDENTIFIER(__delete__);
    _Py_IDENTIFIER(__set__);

    if (value == NULL)
        res = call_method(self, &PyId___delete__, "(O)", target);
    else
        res = call_method(self, &PyId___set__, "(OO)", target, value);
    if (res == NULL)
        return -1;
    Py_DECREF(res);
    return 0;
}
```

This uses `call_method`, which bypasses `__getattribute__`, `__getattr__`, and the instance dict, but performs descriptor handling like a normal attribute lookup.

Note that there are two levels of descriptor handling here - we're in the middle of handling the `MyClass.d` descriptor, but now we need to consider whether the `__set__` or `__delete__` methods of the `MyClass.d` descriptor are themselves descriptors. They're not, but if they were implemented with regular Python functions, they would have been descriptors, and descriptor handling for Python functions would have bound the `Descriptor` instance as the first argument to its `__set__` or `__delete__` method.

---

For a `__get__` implemented in Python, the CPython internals use [`slot_tp_descr_get`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Objects/typeobject.c#L6359), which performs special method lookup differently.

```
static PyObject *
slot_tp_descr_get(PyObject *self, PyObject *obj, PyObject *type)
{
    PyTypeObject *tp = Py_TYPE(self);
    PyObject *get;
    _Py_IDENTIFIER(__get__);

    get = _PyType_LookupId(tp, &PyId___get__);
    if (get == NULL) {
        /* Avoid further slowdowns */
        if (tp->tp_descr_get == slot_tp_descr_get)
            tp->tp_descr_get = NULL;
        Py_INCREF(self);
        return self;
    }
    if (obj == NULL)
        obj = Py_None;
    if (type == NULL)
        type = Py_None;
    return PyObject_CallFunctionObjArgs(get, self, obj, type, NULL);
}
```

Here, CPython uses `_PyType_LookupId` to look up `__get__` on `type(mc)`, instead of using `call_method` to look it up on `mc`.

Unlike `call_method`, `_PyType_LookupId` does no descriptor handling. Python assumes *without checking* that since it skipped descriptor handling, it needs to bind `self` manually. It explicitly passes `self` (which is the `Descriptor` instance) to the `__get__` method in `PyObject_CallFunctionObjArgs(get, self, obj, type, NULL)`.

---

`__get__` sees the `Descriptor` instance as `first` because Python uses a bad shortcut for second-level descriptor handling internally when calling `__get__`, but not when calling `__set__` or `__delete__`.

Comment: Great description. To my knowledge there isn't a specification for this, but I could be wrong about that. Regardless of the lookup method though, the inconsistency here doesn't seem inappropriate.